# Specifying code path for Applet

Tags: java, html, path, applet

I'm confused on how to correctly specify a applet's code attribute in a webpage. I have an applet with the absolute path of

```
~/workspace/myProject/bin/A/B/C/app.class
```

and my HTML is under myProject. app.class has the package declaration of

```
package A.B.C
```

How do I specify that the page should first look in bin and then A,B,C? If I stick the page in /bin, I can use

```
code = "A/B/C/app.class"
```

and it works fine, but putting it in myProject and trying

```
code = "bin/A/B/C/app.class"
```

doesn't work. I think its because of that package declaration but I don't know how to fix it; i can't change the package declaration. Do I need to use . in someway? I've seen that before and used it in [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692373/applet-trouble-noclassdeffounderror) but trying with various combinations of . instead of / doesn't work either. As a side question, could someone explain what the difference between . and / is? [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) just says its used for delineating file type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use dots instead of the slashes and specify the `CODEBASE` accordingly

```
<applet code="A.B.C.app.class" codebase="bin" width="300" height="200">
</applet>
```

Comment: why don't you need to specify that its under /bin? Is that understood?

Comment: The `bin` is not part of the package structure.

Comment: ok I get that, but I guess I'm confused about why the webpage cares about the package structure at all. Why does that matter when I have to specify where the .class file is?

Comment: The Java plugin loads the applet like any other `JVM` so needs to follow the convention of loading the class in the usual convention i.e. `com.package.foo.MyClass`.

Comment: So does it really matter where I put the HTML? If I put the HTML in `workspace` instead of `myProject`, would this still work? or would I have to add something like `myProject.A.B.C.app.class`

Comment: I think you're looking for the codebase attribute, see update. Aside: Applets download as jars, makes them easier to deploy.

Comment: If the class is `A.B.C.app.class` the code attribute should be `code="A.B.C.app"`

Comment: AFAIK both will work, see [Applet Tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/applet.html)

Comment: @Reimeus:with code = "app.class", the plugin first look for file "app.class" on the server, and then "app/class.class" which it doesn't find.