# NoClassDefFoundError + Appl

Tags: java, html, applet, noclassdeffounderror

I try to create my first Applet. which is called MemoSaver2.java

Also I created html:

```
<html>
<object classid="java:MemoSaver2.class" 
        type="application/x-java-applet"
        archive="MemoSaver2.jar" 
        height="300" width="450" >
        </object>
</html>
```

and this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Memo saver applet</title>
    </head>
    <applet code="ch13.MemoSaver2.class" width = 600 height= 400> 
        Java is not installed. 
    </applet>
</html>
```

But I always get the same error.

> NoClassDefFoundError MemoSaver2( wrong name: ch13/MemoSaver2)

What I should do for running my applet from the browser?

Comment: What is the URL where we can see the applet fail?  Is the applet in a Jar?  Is the applet in a package?  How do you expect anyone to guess the problem without that type of information?

Comment: Try to remove `ch13`, I'm not sure that it's really needed

Comment: Andrew, I haven't url with application. all is locally. Yes applet is in package, it's name is: ch13. Name of the source:MemoSaver2.java. If I need jar file I will do it, but in books they tell only about .class file, isn't so?

Comment: about removing ch13 - of course I tryed this before I ask this question.

Comment: when I run applet from the eclipse apllet viewer show me this tag:       <applet code="ch13.MemoSaver2.class" width=200 height=200>
</applet>  but when I insert it into my html, I get NoClassDefFoundError. Mb I should place html and class file to another dir, or what it need? mb special jar file?

Comment: Solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692373/applet-trouble-noclassdeffounderror?rq=1

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. :)  Maybe you should write up a short answer and when the site allows, accept it.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I did as you tell :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List item
/home/me/workspace/myProject/bin
applet.html

/home/me/workspace/myProject/bin/test
SimpleApplet.class

If the class SimpleApplet is in package test put the HTML in the parent directory (as detailed above), and use this HTML.