# NoClassDefFound error, java

Tags: java, applet, noclassdeffounderror

My class's code:

```
package overviewPack;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ButtonScreen extends JApplet implements ActionListener{

    JButton middle = new JButton();
    Container screen = getContentPane();
    public void init(){

        setVisible(true);
        middle.addActionListener(this);
        screen.add(middle);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == middle){
            System.out.println("hey");
        }

    }
}
```

When I attempt to run it using html, I recieve a noclassdefFound error, with the stacktrace as ButtonScreen(Wrong name: overviewPack ButtonScreen)

Here is my html code: (I use brackets so that the code will turn up in chat as the code and not the finished product).

```html
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
A Simple Program </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
Here is the output of my program:
<APPLET CODE="overviewPack.ButtonScreen.class" codebase = "bin" WIDTH=150 HEIGHT=25>
</APPLET>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have tried many different formats for the html, and looked at many other people's similar, sometimes exactly the same errors, but none of the solutions proposed to other people have worked. I have also looked around on the rest of the net for a solution, but I have found none.

This error happens with all my applets, even this extremely simple applet I did above.

The html file is in the same folder as the class

Comment: Please always post the entire stack trace of errors, and learn to use the four-spaces indent; you can post correct HTML that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applet trouble - NoClassDefFoundError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692373/applet-trouble-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: Seen that one it didnt work :-/
This was the entire stack trace, unless you mean the details bit, which just had a default looking menu thing.

Comment: I said that the html and class were in the same folder, I dunno what else to say, I mean they are both under overviewPack, under bin, but what else do you need/want to know?
Sorry if I come off a bit brash/rude I always seem to have this happen in text speak :-/

Comment: *"said that the html and class were in the same folder"*  Indeed you did.  It was only after I gave the question a little formatting that I noticed that comment of 'same directory'.  :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The HTML file is in the same folder as the class

That is no good.  You need to understand how the parameters in the applet element work.

```html
<APPLET CODE="overviewPack.ButtonScreen.class" codebase="bin" WIDTH=150 HEIGHT=25>
```

Let us say that the HTML is located at: `our.com/applets/applet1.html`.

`codebase = "bin"` would mean the classpath starts with `our.com/applets/bin/`.

`overviewPack.ButtonScreen.class` would therefore need to be found at:

`our.com/applets/bin/overviewPack/ButtonScreen.class`

Note that the package `overviewPack` has become an inherent part of the correct path to the class file.  **That** is where the 'wrong name' is originating from.  The JRE seems to be searching the directory of the HTML, locating the class in the same directory, then loading it to discover it is in the wrong path.

### Code Attribute

```html
<APPLET CODE="overviewPack.ButtonScreen.class" codebase="bin" WIDTH=150 HEIGHT=25>
```

Note the required value is the Fully Qualified Name of the class file. That consists of the package(s) name, followed by the class name, each separated by a dot. E.G.

```
overviewPack.ButtonScreen
```

As opposed to

```
overviewPack.ButtonScreen.class // combination of FQN with file type
```

or

```
overviewPack/ButtonScreen.class // relative file path on server
```

So the opening `APPLET` element should best be:

```html
<APPLET CODE="overviewPack.ButtonScreen" codebase="bin" WIDTH=150 HEIGHT=25>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there is a problem with the .class file extension at the end of the code= attribute.  Some doc I've seen says that the code= attribute has the classname in which case having the .class at the end is wrong.  The classname is: overviewPack.ButtonScreen and the filename is:
ButtonScreen.class

Comment: *"Sometimes there is a problem with the .class file extension at the end of the code= attribute."*  True.  The required value is the Fully Qualified Name of the class file.  That consists of the package(s) name, followed by the class name, each separated by a dot.  E.G. `overviewPack.ButtonScreen` (as opposed to `overviewPack.ButtonScreen.class` or `overviewPack/ButtonScreen.class`).