# ClassNotFoundException in Java

Tags: java, html, jar

I have a strange and fustrating problem.  I loaded all my .class files into a JAR file and placed it on my local web server.  The problem is when I navigated to the page with my JAR I got a big ClassNotFoundExeption.  I am 100% certian this class file is in my JAR.  I also know the JAR file is in the same directory as my XHTML file

Here is the XHTML source

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="000000">
        <center>
            <applet
                archive   = "program.jar"
                code    = "inigui4.class"
                width   = "500"
                height  = "300"
            >

            <param name="cache_option" value="no"> 
            </applet>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Very strange!**

For some reason when I create a hello world applet I get the same problem (could it be with my LightTPD server?

Java source follows

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class inigui4 extends Applet {

    public void init() {
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.drawString("Welcome to Java!!", 50, 60 );

    }
}
```

**Even stranger.**

Now I can't load any applets on the web because I get this error.  I will need to contact Oracle in the morning.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the exception you got. The problem is not that the JAR file itself is not found, but that a class is missing from the JAR...

Comment: How can I tell which file is missing?

Comment: The stack trace tells you that. The long gibberish with ClassNotFoundException in it. Just copy and paste it into the question

Comment: Sorry if I sound dumb but where can I find the gibberish?  I am just clicking on the applet error window and getting ClassNotFoundExeption inigui4.class

Comment: Post that. The whole string, that makes it to the screen.

Comment: Have you checked in your browser's Java console?

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by multiple reasons, but the most probable one is that you haven´t specified the package of the class you´re using. Look at the answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396646/load-class-myapplet-not-found-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-why-am-i-gett).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using packages you have have to prefix inigui4.class by [its relative path into the jar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/applet.html)

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but how can I do  stack trace on the exception... I never really learned how to run stack traces

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
        <applet
            archive   = "program.jar"
            code    = "inigui4.class"
            width   = "500"
            height  = "300"
        >
```

Here, you specify **`inigui4.class`** - but in your Java code:

```
public class inigui_rb extends Applet {
   ...
}
```

This is **`inigui_rb`**. Try:

```
         <applet
            archive   = "program.jar"
            code    = "inigui_rb.class"
            width   = "500"
            height  = "300"
        >
```

The `ClassNotFoundException` should go away.

Also please adhere to the [Java coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) when coding! In this case:

- **Class Names Begin With Capitals!**
- **ClassNamesDoNotContainUnderscoresInsteadTheyAreCamelCased!**

Comment: No, this is a new program I changed the name of the class when I built the hello world program

Comment: Ok, then please update the question to be coherent, as it is misleading this way.